# Wrong List<> values in Html Helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel with a list of integers that could be edited. At post event the elements equal to 0 are deleted and the list is reordered.

In this sample code, if I change the value 30 to 0 and submit, the view should shows 4 inputs with values "10, 20, 40, 50" but I get "10, 20, 0, 40" if I use any HtmlHelper like EditorFor ou TextBoxFor.

If I replace the html helper with a input tag all works fine.

```
public ActionResult IntegerList()
{
    return View(new IntegerListViewModel() { List = new List<int>() { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 } });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult IntegerList(IntegerListViewModel integerListViewModel)
{
    integerListViewModel.List = integerListViewModel.List.Where(i => i > 0).OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
    return View(integerListViewModel);
}

public class IntegerListViewModel
{
    public IList<int> List { get; set; }
}

// @ view
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.List.Count; i++)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(integer => Model.List[i]) // Wrong output
            @Html.TextBoxForFor(integer => Model.List[i]) // Wrong output
            <input type="text" value="@Model.List[i]" /> // Correct output
            @Model.List[i].ToString() // Correct output
        </div>
    }
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a tricky one. Honestly, I wasn't able to find out what's going on. I thought it could be a browser issue, but inspecting the network tab you notice that the form actually returns with the wrong data.

What I'm posting here isn't a solution, but a recommendation that will also solve this problem: [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

When you have a POST action that returns a view, you are open to duplicated transactions. Because the last request sent from the browser was that POST, if the user hits F5, it will POST again.

You could easily solve this using the following example:

```
    public ActionResult IntegerList()
    {
        var model = new IntegerListViewModel() { List = new List<int>() { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 } };

        if (this.TempData.ContainsKey("IntegerList"))
            model.List = (List<int>)this.TempData["IntegerList"];

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IntegerList(IntegerListViewModel integerListViewModel)
    {
        var list = integerListViewModel.List.Where(i => i > 0).OrderBy(i => i).ToList();

        this.TempData.Add("IntegerList", list);

        return this.RedirectToAction("IntegerList");
    }
```

I'm using `TempData` to send data from one action to the other, that's fine. You could also send URL parameters (GET parameters) with this redirect, just find the appropriate override.

As I said, I'm not answering your origional question, but solving it with a recommendation for another issue.

Comment: this code is just a sample to illustrate the problem in a more complex software, but thanks for your considerations, it's really interesting.

Comment: @MaxBündchen In a more complex software, you'll be likely storing data somewhere and then retrieving on the other action. Actually, it's even more important to take care with duplicated transactions, so PRG is really a good idea.